# If i use android:digits in edittext then single line restriction is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-edittext

I have used the android:digits in editText view to accept only letters, but when i set this property then single line restrict is not working.

It always creates new line when i enter more text.

If i remove the digits property, single line restrict works.

```
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1"
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Comment: Your code is working like exactly what it should do. Whenever you enter characters after completing a line, It will create a new line but you can only see one line at once. Now what you want to do?

Comment: @RajatMehra I don't want the editext to create new line, all characters need to show in one line even if i use the "android:digits"

Answer (score 2):

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

will work for you. But since it is deprecated it is not advisable to use it.

But it is the easiest solution for it.

Comment: This way is working, but it already deprecated. Thanks anyways

Comment: Since `maxLines` is not a complete replacement of `singleLine`, so this attribute is not going anywhere. It is deprecated because the performance of `maxLines` is better but when you have no other option then you can use `singleLine` to achieve your desired output.